# Probabilities of measuring $\pm \hbar/2$ along $\hat{n}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, probability

I have an example that I don't understand, especially 2 expressions.

Given a spin in the state $|z + \rangle$, i.e., pointing up along the z-axis what are the
probabilities of measuring $\pm \hbar/2$ along $\hat{n}$?

I have these 2 expressions

$$|+\rangle_n = cos(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}|+\rangle +sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle$$
$$|-\rangle_n = sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}|+\rangle -cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle$$

I'm not sure to fully understand what that means.
Is $|+\rangle_n$ only used for a particle in the spin $|z + \rangle$ and $|+\rangle_n$ is a linear combination of $\hbar/2$ and $- \hbar/2$.
Hence, the probability to have $\hbar/2$ is $|cos(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}(1,0)|^2$, knowing that $|+\rangle = (1,0)$

I'm not that convince about my explanation. This is not based on anything.

Answer (score 1):

For any direction there are two eigenstates of $\hat L \cdot \hat n$ ($L_n$ for short), with eigenvalues $\pm \frac 1 2 $. In bra-ket notation, they are referred to as:

$$ |\pm\rangle_n$$

unless $\hat n = \hat z$, then the subscript $n$ is omitted.

Oh, and $\hat n$ is obtained by rotating $\hat z$ by $\phi$ (azimuth) and $\theta$ (polar).

Answer (score 1):

Combine/invert your two basis changes for your state,
$$
|+\rangle=\cos(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}|+\rangle_n+ \sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle_n ,
$$
so the probability of measuring $\hbar/2$ along $\hat n$ is $| \langle \hat n +|z+\rangle|^2=\cos^2\theta/2,$ "accidentally" coincident with your answer, given the immaterial $\phi$ dependence. Proceed to likewise get the probability of measuring $-\hbar/2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure to understand.
I thought that $$|+\rangle_n = cos(\theta/2)e^{-i\phi/2}|+\rangle +sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle$$ was the state of the spin in direction $n$ in the $S_z$ basis.

Comment: That’s true, but that’s not the state you are in, which you must reexpress in terms of the states you measure: that’s the point!  See my edit.